# Gdb stops when viewing variables in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, gdb

When debugging a c++ app, and hitting a breakpoint, gdb terminates the debug session when I click on a variable to expand its content in the Variables panel.
The displayed message is: `<terminated, exit value: 0>gdb (10.1.90.20210103)`
Printing the variable from the Debugger Console works correctly.

Debugging was working OK some weeks ago. The major changes that happen recently was a debian upgrade from 10 to 11 (bullseye), and an upgrade of the Eclipse version.

Activating gdb traces following [where can I find GDB traces](https://wiki.eclipse.org/CDT/User/FAQ#I.27ve_been_asked_for_.27gdb_traces.27.2C_where_can_I_find_them.3F), I could see the commands sent to GDB, but no particular error before GDB stopped.

Any idea of what could cause this issue?

Eclipse Version: 2021-12 (4.22.0), Build id: 20211202-1639 running on linux debian bullseye.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question.

After checking related answers, I suspect that the problem is linked to stl pretty printing in Eclipse (which was working fine before). I tried different version of Eclipse and gdb, and finally managed to fix the issue by using a previous version of gdb (8.3 instead of 10.1).

Here is the procedure that I followed (I'm not sure all steps are mandatory).

- Reinstalled eclipse from scratch
- Deleted the .metadata directory and recreated the eclipse workspace
- Downloaded version 8.3 of gdb sources, and compiled it with python support ('./configure --with-python'). Note that libgmp-dev and python2.7-dev debian packages must be installed.
- Copied gdb-8.3 somewhere under /usr/local/
- Updated eclipse preference settings : C-C++/Debug/GDB and change GDB Debugger to the pach where gdb 8.3 executable was located under /usr/local/.
- Checked in Debugger Console that the right gdb version is displayed. If this is not the case, you may have to set gdb using Debug As.../Debug Configurations/Debugger/GDB Debugger

Comment: Thanks Solved my issue on Ubuntu 20.04 which comes pre packaged with gdb 9.2. Simply installed gdb 8.2 and it solved the issue